# NSPersistentDocument to be marked as not "dirty"/edited after internal initiation

Tags: core-data, nspersistentdocument

I have a NSPersistentDocument (CoreData) that I initiate before I present it to the user. That means that I create some internal core data objects and add them to the document/persistent store/managed object context.

However, that means that even if no user activity is happening the document shows the saving dialog when the document is closed. I would like it to be marked as not dirty and no saving dialog as no real change happened.

Any idea? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handled that problem by implementing this in `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Disable Undo
    [self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [[self undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];

    // Do your initialization thing

    // Process changes to the object graph and reenable Undo
    [self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [[self undoManager] enableUndoRegistration];

    // Rest of awakeFromNib, if any
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dirty state is connected to `documentEdited`. `documentEdited` is set by `updateChangeCount:`. `updateChangeCount:` is automatically called by the undo manager.

Call `[[self undoManager] removeAllActions];` or its Swift equivalent to remove the dirty state.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it. But removeAllActions undoes all my changes. However, I need my under-the-hood initiation as it is the meta-model for the users input.  :-(

Comment: Actually, I forgot to take the first part into consideration. I now did both from within the document:
`self.updateChangeCount(.changeCleared)
db.managedObjectContext?.undoManager?.removeAllActions()`

db is my top-level core data object. Together it works!

Comment: unfortunately, there was a subsequent error with my initiation not fully successful. I cannot recommend this approach.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why it does work in my app. I'm adding the data in `initWithType:error:`.